# Split cube in half

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender. I wanted to split a cube in half.

I found these three steps:

1. Go in edit mode by pressing 'Tab'
2. Press 'B' for choosing the area that you want to be cut
3. Press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete vertices/edges etc.

When I press <kbd>X</kbd> the whole cube is deleted (even I selected only the vertices to be deleted). Why?

Comment: imho that happens because you have no vertices in the center of the cube so if, eg, you select with B the "left side" vertices and then delete (X) you are left with only the "right side" vertices, and you see no cube anymore (you should have only the "right side" face, and it should be visible somehow).

Comment: anyway, there are several ways to "cut a cube in two": using bisect (but imho is difficult to precisely control the cut), or creating a "center" edge loop (with CTRL-R) or even using the "knife" (K) tool, and then deleting as you did before. You could even use booleans, but it's a bit overkill for just a simple cube.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>B</kbd> - it is a select tool, not a cut tool.

If you want to cut something with line try to use **bisect**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest Loop Cut .
(For if you want exact half, see point 5)

1. Go in edit mode.
2. do "ctrl+R", go over the mesh, move a bit to get the right cut (you'll see what I mean by that).
3. now press "left click" to select the cut.
4. you
   can move the cut (by moving the mouse) to desired position.
5. press:
   "right click", for exact middle cut.
           or
   "left click", for the selected cut.
6. now select one side of the vertices and delete those.

Answer (score 2):

Another (more precise imho) is using the knife tool, with "midpoint snap" option and "cut through" mode activated. Follow me:

here is your cube

[image]

now move to front (or side) view

[image]

now activate the knife <kbd>K</kbd>, and activate the "cut through" mode pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>, and remember to set the "midpoint snap" (keeping <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed) just before clicking left to start the cut.

keep an ey eon the "status bar", as highlighted below, to be sure of your knife operation mode:

[image]

if you are keeping <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed, the "start cut" green square preview will stick to the midpoint of that edge.

[image]

now drag to the bottom edge always keeping <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed, to set the "end cut" preview point. If unsure or made wrong steps, press <kbd>esc</kbd> to retry from the start. When perfect, press <kbd>enter</kbd>, and the cut will be made.

If you remembered to activate also "cut through" mode pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> at the beginning, you have this:

[image]

and selecting one side of vertices

[image]

you get a perfect (and easy) half cube shape

[image]

it's simpler than it seems, looking at it in action:

[image]