# How to control how a loop-cut will work?

Tags: mesh, extrude

I have been trying to learn the basics of Blender and am slowly getting how it works. But for this project I am trying to make a basic room with a door one end and a fireplace in another wall.

So far, I've make a floor from a cube, then loop-cut around the edges and extruded upwards for walls. But when I want to loop cut to make the fireplace it is cutting all around the floor as well, its this the only way to do it since its all "one piece"? (pic below)

The reason I ask as this as some more important implications to how I work , just before I started this, I had to quit another one I made because I tried to make the floor and then extrude each wall one after the other. When I did this after i got to the 3rd wall the loop-cut was only cutting thru half the floor and seemed to take a strange route so I just quit and started over.
(note: on the one I quit, I had been joining the edges together also using ALT-M)

Heres the pick which i think illustrates what Im trying to say ( I only want to cut the wall (but of course it needs to cut thru both front and back of the wall cube):

[image]

[image]

Comment: imho using the loop cut tool will preserve a good geometry (but creates more than you wish). Knife tool can do what you want, but you'll get easily worse geometry (ngons). You'll thank loop cut later.

Comment: ok thanks. I will persist with loop cut and try to get my head around it. I had now managed to make the hole for the fireplace but now I cannot loopcut on of the walls to extrude the bit out for where the fire will be. I've added another screenshot

Comment: Does "Add vertex" and then "Fill" create worse ngons?

Comment: lol i tried adding lots of vertices with "Subdivide" and "Fill", but when I try to select the faces I made it just selects the whole face and ignores my subdivisions

Comment: Idk how, bit you already have now some ngon (faces with more than 4 vertices): that is not impossible to use but will work bad with tools designed for quad geometry (as visible in the new picture). Take your time learning modeling.

Comment: hmm ok thanks, i dont know how because I was careful to join all the edges up with merge and not overlap but guess can just keep trying

Comment: see this other (related) question to learn about possible use of knife tool instead of loop cut https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82987/split-cube-in-half